# Is there a general library for adding simple reference functions to YAML/JSON, like in CloudFormation?

Tags: json, templates, yaml

Is there a library or specification for adding simple functions or parameters to YAML or JSON files, similar to the [Intrinsic Functions in CloudFormation templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) but without needing to use CloudFormation?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm *not* looking for anything connected to AWS. Just something *like* AWS's CloudFormation template language.

For example, say I want to represent some configuration values like these:

```yaml
serverSettings:
  env: DEV
  url: "example.dev"
  isLive: no
```

But I want to make the file more easily configurable. I'm looking for a way to represent the same values for production I would only be changing the top level `DEV` vs `PROD`, and not have to dig through and make sure everything is updated.

Here's a quick example of the sort of thing I'm looking for (with cloud-formation-like syntax):

```yaml
params:
  env: DEV
options:
  url:
    DEV: "example.dev"
    PROD: "example.com"
  isLive:
    DEV: no
    PROD: yes
serverSettings:
  env: !Get params.env
  url: !GetFromMap params.env options.url
  isLive: !GetFromMap params.env options.isLive
```

Does anything like this exist already?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [CloudFormation macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) to pre-process the templates the way you want using a lambda function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made an edit to clarify my question. I'm not looking for something connected with AWS CloudFormation. I'm looking for a tool that has similar functions but that can be applied to any generic YAML file.

Comment: @APoor Tterraform can read and parse YAML files. So this could be a good start. Have you looked at it?

Comment: No I haven't. Thank you, I'll check it out!